# Angular 4 CLI too slow after ng serve and when updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have pasted a screenshot after i run ng serve. it is on 34946 ms. it is pretty slow and it is hurting the performance of our team. When we also update our code, it takes too long to reload the page.

[image]

My version of angular is Angular CLI version (1.2.7)

Is this an issue or is this normal in Angular CLI?

We already have around 40 components on the project but i am not sure if it affects the loading performance.

Here is the specs of my PC just incase.

[image]

Comment: Do you put any argument when serving ?

Comment: i am just using plain "ng serve" command on terminal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i solved my problem. What happened is that our components and other resources are all imported in ***app.module.ts***. Because of this, the page loads all the resources every time the page loads. My solution was to apply **Lazy Loading** to load only those resources that are specific to the routes that i am accessing and it did fix up the loading issue.

Comment: "My solution was to apply Lazy Loading" it is still not clear what you mean by lazy loading. If you could elaborate it, with an example. Then It would be better.

Comment: @Voiltaire please comment with an example to help the community who are facing a problem right away like your's.

Comment: How to apply lazy loading ?

Comment: This is how - https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 8):

You have this problem is because your dev PC have not enough memory to handle the build as *nodejs* is consuming a lot of memory when you run expensive `npm` tasks. And the bigger your project the more memory is required to complete the task. The problem can get even worse if you want to run `ng serve` + `ng t` + `ng whatewer` at the same time.

Check the *Task manager* -> *Perfomrmance tab* then run `ng serve` and you will see what I am talking about.

I had struggled by the same problem until I put another 8gb RAM in my dev PC.

So yes it is normal.

Comment: I'm watching it and it takes only 55% of my RAM. Not enough?

Comment: @Jeb50 how much RAM you've got in total?

Comment: 8 GB, everything goes very well except `ng serve` takes 30 seconds to show percentage.

Comment: I'm at 16GB and takes 1-2 min to recompile using --aot.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @java-addict301 how big is your project? what is your cli version?

Comment: Hi @Kuncevič - 432 components (~2200 files) version: 7.3.9

Comment: @Kuncevič we're using lazy loading for our ~60 modules

Comment: @java-addict301 yeah i c, quite a big so that is why it is taking so much time. I would try the latest cli to see if you can get any speed gains using that.

Answer (score 2):

You Just Need to update angular cli version I hope this will solve your issue

```
 npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

If this one Does not solve your Issue Means Just Run using this Cmd

```
 ng serve --sourceMap=false
```