# How to quickly view results of HTML+CSS edits while developing with Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli, livereload

I am currently developing an app using Angular (Angular 4.3.1 to be precise) using the CLI (version 1.2.4) on Windows 8.

Whenever I make a change to some HTML or CSS, I want to refresh the page to quickly see the result. However, `ng serve` takes a very long time (i.e. about 30 seconds each time) to rerender everything, which makes developing very time consuming and frustrating. For small changes, I can often experiment in Chrome Developer Tools, but for slightly larger changes I need to change it in my IDE and quickly see the results.

Is there some way to do this with Angular? I'm sure lots of people have this same issue but I cannot find any documentation about it.

Comment: This is working by default in my Angular 2 and Angular 4 apps. Didn't do anything specific to get it work. What's the OS and angular CLI version are you using? There was a bug in certain CLI version which has been fixed now,

Comment: For me, it only takes about 3-4 seconds after a save.  I'm not sure why it takes 30 seconds for a change for you, could be a config setting.

Comment: @SangramNandkhile added CLI and OS version info

Comment: For me the CLI also only takes 1-3 seconds to reflect changes, maybe you should consider updating it to the latest version, as they fixed some bugs regarding hmr performance. Also at least for me running the CLI on a windows system is a few seconds slower then running it on Linux.

Comment: @CodyBugstein what is inside your `assets` folder ? is there any big size files in it? What is you dist folder size if you do `ng build` ? What is your `PC RAM` spec? When Angular CLI is compiling the thing, how is your `performance tab` is looks like in `task manager`? What is your `node -v` ?

Comment: @Kuncevic I'm using this project as a base and I haven't modified it much. https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter/blob/master/package.json . I have 8GB of RAM. `node -v` is `6.10.3`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818811/angular-4-cli-too-slow-after-ng-serve-and-when-updating